# Refreshing listview in fragment tabs

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-tabs, android-lazyloading

I have to tabs, both containing listviews. I am parsing data and putting them into listview through lazy loading. I was succefull in doing that. However I am face an issue. After loading data into listview of tab1, when I go to tab2 and come back to tab1, all the data in the listview of tab1 gets erased.Same is the case with tab 2 as well. However the data is still there in the array, using which I populated the list view. Could any one please take a look at it. Thanks.

Fragmentactivity class: used to create and display tabs:

```
package com.example.abe;

import java.util.HashMap;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;

public class TabsFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {

    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private HashMap<String, TabInfo> mapTabInfo = new HashMap<String, TabsFragmentActivity.TabInfo>();
    private TabInfo mLastTab = null;

    private class TabInfo {
        private String tag;
        private Class<?> clss;
        private Bundle args;
        private Fragment fragment;

        TabInfo(String tag, Class<?> clazz, Bundle args) {
            this.tag = tag;
            this.clss = clazz;
            this.args = args;
        }

    }

    class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

        private final Context mContext;

        public TabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }

    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs_layout);
        initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); // set
                                                                                // the
                                                                                // tab
                                                                                // as
                                                                                // per
                                                                                // the
                                                                                // saved
                                                                                // state
        }
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); // save the tab
                                                                // selected
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        TabInfo tabInfo = null;
        TabsFragmentActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost
                .newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("ST"), (tabInfo = new TabInfo(
                "Tab1", Tab1Fragment.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        TabsFragmentActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost
                .newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("CSI"),
                (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab2", Tab2Fragment.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        this.onTabChanged("Tab1");
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }

    private static void addTab(TabsFragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost,
            TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
        tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
        String tag = tabSpec.getTag();
        tabInfo.fragment = activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (tabInfo.fragment != null && !tabInfo.fragment.isDetached()) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(tabInfo.fragment);
            ft.commit();
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }

    public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
        TabInfo newTab = this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
        if (mLastTab != newTab) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            if (mLastTab != null) {
                if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                    ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
                }
            }
            if (newTab != null) {
                if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                    newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this,
                            newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                    ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
                } else {
                    ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
                }
            }
            mLastTab = newTab;
            ft.commit();
            this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }
    }

}
```

Tab1 fragment class- Contains listview:

```
package com.example.abe;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class Tab1Fragment extends ListFragment {
    ListView lv;
    Activity act = this.getActivity();
    Context ct = this.getActivity();
    XMLGettersSetters data;
    boolean loadingMore = false;
    String abc[] = new String[50];
    static int count = 0;
    final int itemsPerPage = 10;
    static ArrayList<String> myListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> myListItems2;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;

    static int size = 0;
    int position = 0;
    int top = 0;
    static String android_array1[];
    ArrayList<String> myListItems3;

    String parsed[] = new String[MainActivity.Sarray1.length];

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        myListItems2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myListItems);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag1_layout, container,
                false);
        lv = (ListView) root.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        parsed = MainActivity.Sarray1;
        for (int j = 0; j < parsed.length; j++) {
            System.out.println("sax" + parsed[j].toString());
        }

        // android_array1=SAXParserActivity.Sarray1;
        // for (int i=0 ; i < android_array1.length ; i++)
        // {
        // System.out.println("a"+android_array1[i].toString());
        // }
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        myListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        int cnt = lv.getCount();
        // if(cnt < 10)
        // {
        // adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
        // android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myListItems);
        // lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        // }
        System.out.println("lv count" + " " + cnt);
        System.out.println("view count" + " " + count);
        // if(cnt!=count)
        // {
        // adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
        // android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myListItems);
        // }

        View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
                R.layout.listfooter, null, false);
        lv.addFooterView(footerView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        // this.setListAdapter(adapter);
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            abc[i] = "ab" + i;
        }
        this.getListView().setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                System.out.println(abc.length);
                System.out.println(count);
                System.out.println("First" + firstVisibleItem);
                System.out.println("Vis" + visibleItemCount);
                position = firstVisibleItem;
                View v = lv.getChildAt(0);
                top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
                int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
                System.out.println("Last" + lastInScreen);
                System.out.println("Total" + totalItemCount);
                if ((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)) {
                    if (count < size) {
                        try {
                            Thread thread = new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
                            thread.start();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                "DATA =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            }
        });
        try {
            Thread thread = new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
            thread.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Runnable loadMoreListItems = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loadingMore = true;
            myListItems3 = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            size = parsed.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < itemsPerPage; i++) {
                if (count < size) {
                    myListItems3.add(parsed[count].toString());
                    myListItems.add(myListItems3.get(i));
                    count = count + 1;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            Log.i("a", "b");
            try {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(returnRes);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("a", "b");
        }
    };
    private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (myListItems3 != null && myListItems3.size() > 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < myListItems3.size(); j++) {
                    adapter.add(myListItems3.get(j));

                    adapter1.add(myListItems3.get(j));

                }
            }
            // setListAdapter(adapter);
            Log.i("a", "b");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            // lv.setSelection(position);
            // lv.setSelectionFromTop(position, top);
            Log.i("a", "b");
            getActivity().setTitle(
                    "Neverending List with "
                            + String.valueOf(adapter.getCount()) + " items");
            loadingMore = false;

        }
    };
}
```

Tab2 fragment class- Also contains listview:

```
/**
* 
*/
package com.example.abe;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;

/**
* @author mwho
* 
*/
public class Tab2Fragment extends ListFragment {
    ListView lv;
    Activity act = this.getActivity();
    Context ct = this.getActivity();
    XMLGettersSetters data;
    boolean loadingMore = false;
    String abc[] = new String[50];
    static int count = 0;
    final int itemsPerPage = 10;
    static ArrayList<String> myListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> myListItems2;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    static int size = 0;
    int position = 0;
    int top = 0;
    ArrayList<String> myListItems3;
    String parsed[] = new String[MainActivity.Sarray2.length];

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {

            return null;
        }

        myListItems2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myListItems2);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag1_layout, container,
                false);
        lv = (ListView) root.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        parsed = MainActivity.Sarray2;
        for (int j = 0; j < parsed.length; j++) {
            System.out.println("sax" + parsed[j].toString());
        }
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        myListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
                R.layout.listfooter, null, false);
        this.getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            abc[i] = "ab" + i;
        }
        this.getListView().setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                System.out.println(abc.length);
                System.out.println(count);
                System.out.println("First" + firstVisibleItem);
                System.out.println("Vis" + visibleItemCount);
                position = firstVisibleItem;
                View v = lv.getChildAt(0);
                top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
                int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
                System.out.println("Last" + lastInScreen);
                System.out.println("Total" + totalItemCount);
                if ((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)) {
                    if (count < size) {
                        try {
                            Thread thread = new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
                            thread.start();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                "DATA =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        try {
            Thread thread = new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
            thread.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Runnable loadMoreListItems = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loadingMore = true;
            myListItems3 = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            size = parsed.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < itemsPerPage; i++) {
                if (count < size) {
                    myListItems3.add(parsed[count].toString());
                    myListItems.add(myListItems3.get(i));
                    count = count + 1;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            Log.i("a", "b");
            try {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(returnRes);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("a", "b");
        }
    };
    private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (myListItems3 != null && myListItems3.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < myListItems3.size(); i++)
                    adapter.add(myListItems3.get(i));
            }
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            Log.i("a", "b");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            // lv.setSelection(position);
            lv.setSelectionFromTop(position, top);
            Log.i("a", "b");
            getActivity().setTitle(
                    "Neverending List with "
                            + String.valueOf(adapter.getCount()) + " items");
            loadingMore = false;
        }
    };

}
```